# How can I log the command I typed in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb

In GDB, I can turn logging on with "set logging on", but this only logs the results of my commands, and not the command itself. It would be useful if I could see the command typed as well. Is there any way to log the command typed?

Comment: Turns out there's a solution today: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52146678/4561887 and my additions to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63403856/4561887.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `man script`.

See also this ancient [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8822). The fact that this hasn't been fixed in 10 years makes me believe that it's unlikely to ever be fixed.

Most GDB developers use `emacs`, run GDB from inside of `emacs`, and get the functionality you desire "for free".

Comment: Thanks. Although far from ideal, this appears to be the best way to go for now. I may have to grab the GDB source and just implement the feature/push a patch myself! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something beyond

$ set history save

?

you could set special file for history

set history filename ~/.the_history

Comment: Yes. History is nice, but it just dumps everything at the end of the session. It would be better to be able to see results and history interleaved, ie:

x/x &ptr
(next line) 0xdeadbeef: 0x0

(Edit: added the next line part to make it clearer, because comments don't seem to care about new line formatting)